# UIImageView UIScrollView HighRes Image memory warning

Tags: uiscrollview, memory-management, didreceivememorywarning

I'm populating a UIScrollView on iPad with above 10 photos fullscreen in landscape mode (1024x768). I'm facing out a very big problem: I load all the UIImageView asynchronously using GDC, and the add all the view to the ScrollView as subview.
When I load a different gallery, first I remove all the View in the UIScrollVIew, and then reload asynchronously all the thing. 
If I don't switch between the gallery fast, there's no problem; instead, if I switch between a gallery and other, I receive different memory warning and the application crash. I look with instruments, but there's no leak and the memory consumpion is intensive when I add all the view to subview, but it's not raising.
What can be the problem? Maybe I can use NSAutoreleasePool to force the purging of objects?

Answer (score 2):

When you use max resolution photos inside scrollView you can face memory problems

If you have a small scrollView and you want to show thumbnails you can't use the full size photo for the thumbnail you should create in pixelmator, Photoshop etc. a small photo of your photos with this approach you won't face memory problems

If you have a full screen scrollView with full screen imageViews you can remove fromSuperView the images that aren't visible in the scrollView with this approach all your memory problems will disappear

I hope this help

Good luck